# Install the same package on two different versions of Python

Tags: python

I already have pretty table installed on Python 3.6 but I want to install it on python 3.8. So when I do `pip install prettytable`, it shows that the package has already been installed for 3.6 but like I said that I also want it on Python 3.8.

How can I do that? I need both versions of Python for different projects. I use VSCode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Answer (score 0):

You can check which python versions you have and where are they stored by running:

```sh
whereis python
```

Then knowing where is your python3.8 installed, just run this with the absolute path.

For example:

```sh
/usr/bin/python3.8 -m pip install prettytable
or
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 -m pip install prettytable
```

Comment: this is what it shows : zsh: command not found: python3.8

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your system and on the way you can start the different Python versions.

On Windows, you would use the `py` launcher:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install package_name
```

On Linux or any other Unix-like, you normally run directly the various installed python executable with their version as a suffix, so it should be:

```
python3.8 -m pip install package_name
```

Comment: hey, I use a MacBook .

Comment: @angadsinghbedi: If I am not mistaken, the underlying system should be Darwin which is derivated from BSD Unix. So the Unix-like method should work (the exact name of the executable may slightly vary among systems, some adding `-` or `.` character in the name)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative to dealing with different python versions on your PC, I extremely recommend using `anaconda` (or the minimal version `miniconda`) in such cases.

Miniconda is easy to use and helps you manage your python environments. Putting myself in your shoes, I would install `miniconda` from [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), and do the following.

Open `anaconda prompt` and type:

```
conda create -n some_env_name python=3.8
conda activate some_env_name
pip install prettytable
```

You can follow [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) document on how to activate a python environment in `VS CODE`.

Comment: btw forgot to mention that miniconda comes with a `base` python environment, which is the default one.